# Solve $2\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}+\sqrt{x-\frac{4}{x}}=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve  this equation 
$$2\sqrt{1-\tfrac{2}{x}}+\sqrt{x-\tfrac{4}{x}}=x$$

I tried to solve on my computer, but then it has a root that is not too nice.  Can you help me?

Comment: try squaring each side of the equation and then use some root multiplication properties

Comment: how?, i don't understand, we will have an equation don't have "sqrt" ???

Comment: This is an irreducible sixth degree equation, and I'd be surprised to learn that it's solvable in radicals.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$\begin{align} 2\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}+\sqrt{x-\frac{4}{x}}& =2\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x}}+\sqrt{\frac{x^2-4}{x}}\\ &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(2\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x-2}\sqrt{x+2}\right) \\ & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(\sqrt{x-2}\cdot (2+\sqrt{x+2})\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: yes, i know that, but it dosen't go far.

Comment: @RoadHuman As MathNoob's answer, square both sides of this expression (the right-hand side would be $x$, of course). I think that the manipulation it's easier with this expression.

Answer (score 1):

Square both sides to get $$4(1-\frac 2x)+4\sqrt{(1-\frac 2x)(x-\frac 4x)}+x-\frac 4x=x^2$$
$$\implies 4-\frac{12}{x}+x-x^2=4\sqrt{(1-\frac 2x)(x-\frac 4x)}$$
Again
$$\implies x^4-2 x^3-7 x^2+\frac{144}{x^2}+32 x-\frac{96}x-8=16(1-\frac 2x)(x-\frac 4x)$$
$$\implies x^6-2 x^5-7 x^4+16 x^3+24 x^2-32 x+16=0$$
But this polynomial has no real roots, so therefore there is no solution to the problem.

Comment: `\left({expression}\right)` will prevent your fractions "sticking out" of their parentheses.